# Errors when cross compiling C++/Objective-C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, objective-c++

I have a C++ library being referenced by an Objective-C++ project.  The library compiles fine on its own and the Objective-C++ project compiles fine until I instantiate the first class from the library (using an object pointer).  Before using the class from my library I had references to stl `string` objects that didn't cause problems.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      __verify_callback_c in *************.a(cxx_db.o)
      DbEnv::_stream_message_function(__db_env const*, char const*) in *************.a(cxx_env.o)
      DbEnv::_stream_error_function(__db_env const*, char const*, char const*) in *************.a(cxx_env.o)
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::fail() const", referenced from:
      __verify_callback_c in *************.a(cxx_db.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_db.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_dbc.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_dbt.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_env.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_mpool.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_txn.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in *************.a(cxx_lock.o)
      ...
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_db.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_dbc.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_dbt.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_env.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_mpool.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_txn.o)
      ___tcf_0 in *************.a(cxx_lock.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So far I've found that errors like these can be caused by:

1. Having a file type of .m instead of .mm
2. Creating a C++ object in my Objective-C++ without using a pointer

I'm assuming it's some sort of cross-compile error, but I don't know where to look.  Ideas on what it could be?

EDIT:

```
Build Settings:
C++ Standard Library = libc++
C++ Language Dialect = c++0x
```

These are in my top-level project.  The contained library is using these as well (it references an outside library as well, and the header path was no longer found when added it to my main project - I had to add it to my main project settings).

Edit 2:
Here is the build step that fails:

Ld /Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator.app/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator normal i386
    cd /Users/*user*/Documents/Projects/Tests/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Intermediates/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator.build/Objects-normal/i386/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -lstdc++ /Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libBerkeleyDB.a -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/*user*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator-bgnkrqnronvtkoaongfsdturoklb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator.app/BerkeleyDBHelloWorldSimulator

Comment: Those aren't the whole errors, it would help to quote the entirety of them. They look like link errors, not compile errors, though, so are you sure you're linking against the C++ standard library? (libstdc++.dylib)

Comment: The only thing I clipped off was the name of the library.  It's a static library though, not a dylib (I'm compiling for iOS).

Comment: There should be something *above* the "referenced from" lines, which will tell you the actual error. (I still suspect a link error) Does the error occur linking your library or overall project? Does your library link against libstdc++, or your app? Or both?

Comment: You're right.  I was using the errors from an unexpanded list.  I fixed it now.

Comment: If it's relevant, my library is referencing the Berkeley BD library, but I've had no problems referencing that library directly from Objective C++ code.

Comment: All the undefined symbols are part of the standard c++ library. If you really, really have got `libstdc++.dylib` in the list of libraries to link against (xcode app target settings: "build phases", "link binary with libraries"), I have a feeling it's from the wrong SDK. If I right-click the entry in my project that uses a mix of ObjC, ObjC++ and C++ (and which works and is in the app store) and select "show in Finder", it takes me to the file at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib`. Check that yours is the same.

Comment: Also worth checking: look at the raw build log and see if the linker is warning you about ignored files and frameworks. XCode is very good at not showing those.

Comment: Well... linking to libstdc++.6.dylib resolves my linking errors, but why? Linking to libstdc++.dylib in the same location doesn't fix the errors.

Comment: Hmm. Curious, libstdc++.dylib is normally a symlink to libstdc++.6.dylib, so it should make no difference. Check for any extra library search paths that might be set for your target. Maybe it's picking up libstdc++.dylib in another (wrong) location?

Comment: I checked and both libstdc++ and libstdc++.6 point to libstdc++.6.0.9, but for some reason the non-6 one is 17 bytes and the 6 one is21 bytes, so they must be different in some way.  Very strange either way.  Pointing to libstdc++.6.0.9 also works

Comment: Anyway, post something to the effect of "missing link to libstdc++.dylib" and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's taken us some time to get to something approaching a solution in the comments thread, so I'm going to summarise it here:

This type of error is caused by not successfully linking to the correct `libstdc++.dylib`, the standard C++ library. Sometimes, you forget to add it, sometimes XCode gets confused.

First of all, make sure you are indeed linking to it in your app target's settings: it must appear in "build phases", "link binary with libraries".

If it's there, but still failing to link, check the raw build log for any warnings that XCode might be hiding from you: e.g. about wrong architecture. This means you're linking to the wrong version of the file - e.g. linking against the simulator or OSX version instead of that in the `iPhoneOSx.y.sdk` directory. In the past, with XCode 3, this was really easy to get wrong, and the only way to fix it was to try every single different `libstdc++.dylib` that XCode offered until one worked. XCode4 normally only offers one, in addition to the names with version numbers. You should normally pick the dylib without a version number.

Make sure all subprojects that may link against `libstdc++.dylib` use the same version in the same location.

Check the "Library Search Paths" and "Framework Search Paths" for any paths that you didn't add yourself. I've had XCode set paths to old SDKs here, which confused the linker.

Finally, sometimes it helps to just remove the reference to `libstdc++.dylib`, clean the project, quit and restart XCode, and re-add the reference.

Comment: I rechecked my libs and it turns out libstdc++.dylib is a reference to libstdc++.6.dylib which is a reference to libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib so possibly xcode doesn't know how to resolve 2 levels of indirection.

Comment: It should normally be able to handle 2 levels of symlinking. All I can think of is that it's actually looking at a file with the same name in another directory. Linking to libstdc++.6 is a perfectly acceptable solution though, so go with that.

Comment: So I would have thought.  There must be something different about the second link: ls -l libstdc++.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1551312 Sep 16 01:23 libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       21 Jan 22 15:27 libstdc++.6.dylib -> libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       17 Jan 22 15:27 libstdc++.dylib -> libstdc++.6.dylib

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you copy & paste the linker command line of a build that fails from the XCode build log? Maybe I can spot something.

Comment: Sorry, I've just fallen in that you're specifying clang's `libc++` - as a test, try switching the setting to libstdc++. I've never used libc++, so I'm not sure how complete it is, particularly on OSX 10.6. It doesn't explain why everything works when you choose a specific version of libstdc++ - maybe there's some special-casing in the clang linker? Oh and thanks for the bounty. Not sure it's justified, we still haven't figured it out 100%. :-)

Comment: That actually fails to build.  I'm using the LLVM with Clang and that requires libc++ for C++0x. See libcxx.llvm.org for details on that.

Comment: Right, OK. I'm just not sure on the relationship between libstdc++ and libc++ - whether libc++ still relies on libstdc++ for the more mundane things like I/O streams (which is where your link errors originate), or if it's a complete replacement.

Comment: It's a complete rewrite from the ground up.  C++0x required basically a complete rewrite, so instead of breaking the ABI for the old library they just wrote a new one.

Comment: Are you using any libraries that might be using libstdc++ internally? This might be confusing the linker which is trying to skip libstdc++ in favour of libc++. That's pretty much all I can think of at this point. If that's not it, you're best off asking Apple developer support directly.

Comment: The berkeley db library I'm using is referencing libstc++.  I spent a little time trying to consolidate everything to using clang/libc++, maybe I should finish that up.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure both your code and the library links against the same C++ standard library.

Comment: I think they do.  My library project is inside my other project and it's my understanding that in that case the library uses the settings on the main project.